# Exporting data from two tables and combining into one file

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, export

Have a question. I have a database called scraped. It has two tables. One called profiles and the other called charges. There is an identifier for each person in the profiles table called ID and a corresponding identifier in the charges table called profile_id. I'd like to export the profiles table, but want to join up all the contents of the charges to make one big flatfile (or table) using the "use query" as an export method. I'm stumped as to how to do this.

One other issue. say john smith has ID of 101, he may have 10 rows In the charges table that correspond to his ID number. Will they all be listed in separate rows in final output or not? If not can they be somehow?

Comment: It sounds like you just need to write a simple join query. `SELECT [list of columns you need] FROM Profiles inner join Charges on Profiles.ID = Charges.profile_id`. If you need all `profiles` whether or not they have a `charge` then change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`. And yes, you'll get a record for every match in the `Charges` table (so 10 for your john smith).

Comment: @beercodebeer you might add it as an answer which can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to write a simple join query.

```
SELECT [list of columns you need] 
FROM Profiles 
INNER JOIN Charges ON Profiles.ID = Charges.profile_id
```

If you need all profiles whether or not they have a charge then change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`.

And yes, you'll get a record for every match in the Charges table (so 10 for your john smith).